# Control ball speed in pong

Tags: javascript, pong

I have this code below, and I'm having a hard time solving this one.
On `dotime` function, i have the ball speed:

```
/* HERE */
function dotime() {
    move1();
    if (myform != null) {
        myform.text3.value = display1();
        myform.score.value = "" + score;
    }
    /* ---Ball Speed--- */
    if (!oops_flag) timerID = setTimeout("dotime()", 190);
    /* ---trying to make ball speed faster--- */
    if (score == 1) {
        timerID = setTimeout("dotime()", 100 - 30);
    }
    timerRunning = true;
}
```

I tried to make the ball move faster but when i do the second "if", the ball just flying too fast.

Thanks in advance,
fufle.

full code:

```
var crlf = "\r\n";
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var dx = 1;
var dy = 1;
var s = "";
var u = 0;
var oops_flag = false;
var score = 0;

function move1() {
    x += dx;
    if (x > 61) {
        x -= 2 * Math.abs(dx);
        if (dx > 0) dx = -dx;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        x += 2 * Math.abs(dx);
        if (dx < 0) dx = -dx;
    }
    y += dy;
    if (y > 24) {
        y -= 2 * Math.abs(dy);
        if (dy > 0) dy = -dy;
        if (Math.abs(x - 2 * u - 1) > 2) {
            oops_flag = true;
        } else {
            score += 1;
        }
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        y += 2 * Math.abs(dy);
        if (dy < 0) dy = -dy;
    }
}

function display1() {
    var s1 = ""
    var i, j;
    if (oops_flag) return "                       Unlucky, Play again?"
    for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 62; i++) {
            /* BALL */
            if (j == y && i == x) s1 += "";
            else s1 += " ";
        }
        s1 += crlf;
    }
    /* DEFENDER */
    var s2 = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        if (u == i) s2 += "▄▄▄▄▄";
        else s2 += "  ";
    }
    return (s1 + s2);
}
var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;
var myform;

function stopclock() {
    if (timerRunning) clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerRunning = false;
}

function startclock(form) {
    myform = form;
    oops_flag = false;
    score = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") > 2) crlf = "\n";
    stopclock();
    dotime();
    // var id= setInterval(frameElement,10000);
}
/* HERE */
function dotime() {
    move1();
    if (myform != null) {
        myform.text3.value = display1();
        myform.score.value = "" + score;
    }
    if (!oops_flag) timerID = setTimeout("dotime()", 100);
    if (score == 1) {
        timerID = setTimeout("dotime()", 100 - 30);
    }
    timerRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: What does "too fast" mean? What do you want?

Comment: This is way too vague. You haven't given near enough information. Coupled with the fact that the code is very poorly formatted, you've made it very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: because the first time and second timer are both running?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two timers running so you need to make it so only one will run.

```
if (!oops_flag) {
    var speed = 100;
    if (score===1) speed = 70;
    timerID = setTimeout(dotime, speed);
}
```

or with a ternary operator

```
if (!oops_flag) {
    var speed = (score===1) ? 70 : 100;
    timerID = setTimeout(dotime, speed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and how can i do 3 different speeds?

Comment: Use `else if() {}`

Comment: No success.
Thank you!